# Problem with Ipevo usb camera

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, camera

I have an Ipevo usb camera and since the last kernel update the camera doesn't work...

Product: P2V Point 2 View USB Document Camera

OS: Linux version 5.3.0-40-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-024) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu

usb camera well detected but uvc kernel driver not loading.
There is no /dev/video0 file created.
here is the result of "dmesg | tail" command :

[ 3390.529798] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: IPEVO Inc.
[ 3390.531093] hid-generic 0003:1778:0214.0006: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [IPEVO Inc. IPEVO Point 2 View] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0
[ 3390.533871] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device IPEVO Point 2 View (1778:0214)
[ 3390.533979] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[ 3390.534597] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 9 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[ 3390.536351] uvcvideo: No streaming interface found for terminal 2.
[ 3390.536357] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.1: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[ 3390.536362] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.1: Entity type for entity Processing 3 was not initialized!
[ 3390.536365] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.1: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 3390.536496] input: IPEVO Point 2 View: IPEVO Point as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/input/input21

there is the same problem on Suse, they resolve the issue with kernel tunning : https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1159811

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I found that :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1861344
I hope I understood the manipulation. I just have to test it with my version